# Django Form fields changing after page refresh

Tags: django, django-3.2

The first time I open this ModelAdmin's /add page, all the fields of the ServiceProvider model are displayed, although I specified with self.fields the fields that should be displayed.
When pressing F5 to reload the page, the unsolicited fields do not appear. I suspected cache, but disabling the caches did not cause changes. The problem with loading all fields is that it also does some heavy querying related to those fields.

```
class ServiceProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.fields = (
            "name_registration",
            "name_social",
            "nome_usual",
            ("gender","document"),
            "department",
            "department_aditionals",
            "picture",
            "active",
        )
        if request.user.has_perm("rh.can_edit_secondary_mail"):
            self.fields = self.fields + ("email_secondary",)

        self.form = ServiceProviderFormFactory(request.user)
        return super().get_form(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)


def ServiceProviderFormFactory(user):
    class ServiceProviderForm(forms.ModelForm):
        ...

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            ...

        class Meta:
            model = ServiceProvider
            exclude = ("",)
```

Comment: pls more detail. What is `unsolicited fields`? Pls update really happend step by step.

Comment: ServiceProvider descends from another model, which descends from another model, which has a user field in OneToOneField. I don't want the user field to be turned into a form field, because it has tens of thousands of records. But the first time the ServiceProvider's ModelAdmin is called, it is bringing in all the fields from the parent classes, including user. If I press F5 on the page, the correct fields are displayed, without the user field.
I noticed that, on first access, ModelAdmin's get_form method is being called twice. When I give F5, only once.

Comment: Your problem is how excluded field `user` from `ServiceProviderAdmin`, and why `user` displayed althought `self.fields` your define not have `user`??

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this. The ModelAdmin fields were being set in the get_form method, but it seems that on first access, Django fetches the list of fields before getting to the get_form method.
As the list of fields was not yet defined, it got all the fields related to the model.
Changing the fields definition from get_form to get_fields solved the problem:

```
class ServiceProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = (
            "name_registration",
            "name_social",
            "nome_usual",
            ("gender","document"),
            "department",
            "department_aditionals",
            "picture",
            "active",
        )
        if request.user.has_perm("rh.can_edit_secondary_mail"):
            fields = fields + ("email_secondary",)

        return fields
```